# How do I use derived controls in my Windows Forms application

Tags: winforms, user-interface

At best, I am a UI novice, but I am a pretty good OO developer (if I don't say so myself). I am confused as to how to work with the designer. I am developing a Windows Forms application.  I have a control (TabPage) that I derived from `System.Windows.Forms.TabPage` that I want to place on a `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl` control.

```
public class MyTabPage : TabPage
{ ... }
```

I am not sure how to get the designer to use my control.

A fellow developer looked at this for me as suggested that I add more information.

I've prototyped a WinForms application.  The application has a `TabControl`, with three tab pages on it.  Each `TabPage` has a `SplitterControl` with a `DataGridView` control in each half of the splitter.  The two `DataGridView` controls form a master-detail view of some data we need to edit.  I've added a bunch of event handlers to each DataGridView control and each time the handler code is placed in the form.  The form is getting pretty crowded and would like to use OO techniques to clean things up.

I would like to redo the prototype now and because each `TabPage` is behaviorally identical, I would like to use OO to abstract away some of the complexity.  This is where my lack of experience with the designer comes in.  There must be a way to use the designer for something more complex than my origonal prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but I thought I would answer this question.

I was able to get the OO implementation I wanted by splitting the control up. The control is implemented pretty much the same as the prototype. I then created a control binder class hirearchy with derived classes to contain the specific behavior(s) I needed. The control has a reference to the binder base class and calls binder functionality as needed.  The derived binders override properties and methods as necessary. Pretty much a textbook OO solution.

Where I was stumbling was in thinking that I needed to have a control hirearchy.

Thanks everyone for your help.  I was under some pressure when I asked this question. It's amazing how much I've learned in the months since.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no real practical solution to your problem.  You'd have to create a custom TabControl as well and give it its own designer so that it will create instances of your derived class instead of the default TabPage class.

Sadly, the TabControlDesigner class in System.Design.dll is internal and can't be derived from.  You'd have to write a complete replacement for it.  That's difficult, it is a pretty advanced designer.  You could have a look-see with Reflector to find out what it takes.

Comment: So how do real UI developers develop their code?  It seems like the designer is great for trivial applications, but useless for any application of substance.  I guess I have a hard time buying that.

Comment: You're rather quick to dismiss it after only one speed-bump.  Customizing a TabPage is very uncommon, it just doesn't do anything very useful that needs to be customized.  It is just a container for controls.  I can't help you with a good answer, you didn't explain why you want to customize it.

Comment: That came across poorly.  I'm not dismissing it, to the contrary, my expectation is that there is likely a way to do what I want, but my lack of experience is hobbling me.  I added more detail to the question hoping to make better sense.  I figured that the TabPage might be the wrong place to do thederivation, so I tried deriving the SplitContainer.  I'm stil missing something.  Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't really changing the behavior of the TabPage, it's just a container after all :).  The TabPage and TabControl are rather tightly coupled, and they probably should be.  Your "control" is what should be placed on the TabPage.  So define your user control as a panel with a splitter and two datagridviews and then just drop your user control on each TabPage in your app.  The Tab Control/Page tandem will still work automatically and your custom code will be in the appropriate control.

Answer (score 1):

**UserControl**

Simply create a user control that contains your control. Then it will be available in the ToolBox window of Visual Studio.

For more details, [Understanding the User Control Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/114xc3e5%28VS.90%29.aspx)...

> A User Control is similar to any other
>   class, but with the added ability to
>   be placed in the Toolbox and displayed
>   on a form.

The tutorial differs a bit from Visual Studio 2010 but I'm sure you will get through it.

---

**TabPage Control**

As for the TabPage control, you can't use it stand-alone in the designer. It must be part of a TabControl.

The TabControl is built to contain TabPage controls. If you use the designer to add/remove any TabPage, in the back-end it does "new TabPage", it can't determine that it needs to create a new instance of your derived class of TabPage.

---

**Other Suggestion**

A TabPage is just a container, I can't figure out why you need to override the TabPage control. I know you have added some information to your question but you may have to revisit it again so we can better understand.

Since the TabPage is a container, you should create a UserControl which contains your SplitContainer and DataGridViews. Therefore you would be able to reuse that UserControl on each TabPage.

The designer is just a complement to UI programming, it is not mandatory. You can add a UserControl to a TabPage without using the designer.

I may be off the track here, if so please provide more details. A visual prototype of what you need may help.

Comment: I figured this part out and thought great. I created a control called MyTabPage derived from TabPage.  When I open MyTabPage in the designer though I don't see how to add (and arrange) the SplitContainer and DataGridView controls.  I then tried the same thing with the SplitContainer control.  The same thing happened ... I don't see how to use the designer to edit my derived controls.